# How do I fix Syntax error near "=" in casez statement?

Tags: verilog, digital-design

For a lab in a digital design course, I am designing a partial ALU. I have defined its operations and am required to use a `casez` statement to govern which function (either addition of a & b w/ overflow checking, bitwise inversion of b, a AND b, and a OR b) is selected by the four 2-bit combos of `sel`:

```
module eightbit_palu(input  wire[7:0] a, b,
                     input  wire[1:0] sel,
                     output wire[7:0] f,
                     output wire ovf);
                     
    wire[7:0] sum, bitInv, bitAnd, bitOr;
    wire sumOvf;
    
    assign sum = a + b;
    assign sumOvf = (a+b>127)||(a+b<-128) ? 1 : 0;
    assign bitInv = !b;
    assign bitAnd = a & b;
    assign bitOr = a | b;
    
    always @(a or b or sel) begin
        casez(sel)
            2'b00: f = sum; ovf = sumOvf;
            2'b01: f = bitInv; ovf = 0;
            2'b10: f = bitAnd; ovf = 0;
            2'b11: f = bitOr; ovf = 0;
        endcase
    end
    
endmodule
```

I have embedded the `casez` statement within an `always @`, but I am getting a syntax error that I believe might be due to the outputs being wires.  I am not sure how to work around that seemingly simple issue.

I tried turning the variables declared before the `assign` statements into regs, but then there was a problem converting them to wires. I would really appreciate some insight as to how Verilog works — unfortunately my professor is teaching in SystemVerilog, yet our labs are required to be in Verilog.

Comment: There's no specific need to use `casez` here if your truth table is correct.

Comment: `!` is a logical negation operator. Since you're doing bitwise inversion, you need use `~` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should change your output wires to `reg` since you are making procedural assignments to them (inside an `always` block).

The other error is that you need to add `begin/end` keywords around multiple statements in each `case` item.  Here is code that compiles cleanly for me:

```
module eightbit_palu(input  wire[7:0] a, b,
                     input  wire[1:0] sel,
                     output reg [7:0] f,
                     output reg ovf);
                     
    wire[7:0] sum, bitInv, bitAnd, bitOr;
    wire sumOvf;
    
    assign sum = a + b;
    assign sumOvf = (a+b>127)||(a+b<-128) ? 1 : 0;
    assign bitInv = !b;
    assign bitAnd = a & b;
    assign bitOr = a | b;
    
    always @(a or b or sel) begin
        casez(sel)
            2'b00: begin f = sum;    ovf = sumOvf; end
            2'b01: begin f = bitInv; ovf = 0;      end
            2'b10: begin f = bitAnd; ovf = 0;      end
            2'b11: begin f = bitOr;  ovf = 0;      end
        endcase
    end
    
endmodule
```

---

You also have a problem with this line:

```
always @(a or b or sel) begin
```

A sensitivity list should include only signals on the RHS of assignments within the block.  Your list incorrectly includes `a` and `b`, and it misses others like `sum`.  You should use an implicit sensitivity list which automatically includes the appropriate signals.

```
always @*
```